# AS3 Security error #2048 socket connection

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, flash

I'm working in a company which creates a huge strategy game with ActionScript3.

I'm one of the developers here and have some issues with Socket Connections.
Socket works perfect when I use it in internal flash player or in firefox debug, it shows socket error #2048 when I'm trying to open the project with Google Chrome.

Here is the code which I use at first before trying to make a Socket Connection.

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

And here is the content of crossdomain.xml file.

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="100-60000" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Then the connect function works to make a Socket Connection with server.

```
instance.host = host;
instance.port = port;
socket = new Socket(host, port); //Initializing the socket
```

Is there any problems with Server or the problem caused by Chrome?
If you had the same issue and found something useful please answer to this question.
I'm searching a solution for a few days, but nothing works.

Comment: Can you confirm that the project works in different browsers, especially IE?

Comment: Yeah it works in IE and Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to launch this swf file from localhost, which is the usual case when debugging, you can add your swf's path to flash player's trusted locations.

This procedure is written [here](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Also try with this simpler cross domain file.

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: I tried it didn't work. I changed my project to work with HTTP requests. Thanks.